# How to Connect MS Defender Secure Scores to Power BI via API?

Tags: powerbi, microsoft-graph-api, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, microsoft365-defender

The Microsoft 365 Defender Portal (https://security.microsoft.com/) has a 'Secure Score' page, which contains the following:

[Screenshot of secure scores breakdown in Defender portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kj3Ie.png)

An overall secure score which is then broken down by **Identity**, **Data**, **Device**, and **Application** secure scores.

I would like to be able to pull these four scores into a Power BI report **via API**; however, I have had some difficulty in putting together a solution. I haven't been able to find an out-of-the-box solution nor a way to custom connect.

This data seems like it could be found in the Microsoft Graph API, but [MS seems to have made connecting Graph to Power Query rather difficult.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connecting-to-graph) I've tried other Defender APIs, but they all seem either outdated or out of scope for what I'm trying to pull.

Can anyone advise? Thanks for reading.

Comment: PowerQuery is not the same as PowerBI so (lack of) graphing in PowerQuery should not impact your graphing in PowerBI using visualizations  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-types-for-reports-and-q-and-a

Comment: Hi, sorry, I meant how to fetch this data via API. So far I've been tracking & graphing this data manually.